# Strange speedtest results on different wireless devices. Why?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, connection, iphone, speedtest

I have different Speedtest results on my Iphone (1st pic) and Win10 PC (2nd pic) which is odd.

[image]

[image]

As one can see, IP is the same, both devices are in the **same** network, on the **same** router, and during the test they were in the **same** location.

I suppose this has something to do with Win10 settings, as Iphone has little impact on network settings.

P.S. This is a public WiFi so I has no access to router dashboard.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here. If it's 'how do I fix this?' the answer is you don't on public wifi.

Comment: The question is what settings to fix to make results the same as on Iphone

Answer (score 0):

Different result appear on same device also in different time. At the time of speed test, the device use max bandwidth. While using speedtest, if you use speedtest on another device, the result are likely to be shown poor result due to max bandwidth are in use by first device.

In your case, as you said you are in public wifi, although you are testing on different device one by one, there is chances that while testing for other device, some other person are using high bandwidth resulting you to poor test result.

Comment: `While using speedtest, if you use speedtest on another device, the result are likely to be shown poor result due to max bandwidth are in use by first device` no, I tested my devices in different points of time

Comment: Though, It is possible that other users existed in the same network degrading its speed, it's unlikely because I did several tests and the results were quite repeatable: perfect on Iphone and shitty on laptop. Why those users not degrade Iphone speed?